# How to implement gallery swiping with dots under

Tags: android

How to implement gallery swiping with dots under? I need to show indicator of the current image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use View pager from the Android Support Library and implement the indicator your self, or check Jake Wharton sample [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator), its very informative.

Answer (score 3):

Create two seperate Views, one for your Gallery and one for the dots. Let your Activity add a listener to your Gallery for swipe actions. Notify your dots view of these actions.