# Android welcome screen - multiple images

Tags: android, material-design, splash-screen

I'd like to make an informative welcome screen with 3-4 images- giving to user for the first time some info about app utility, I'll have skip and next buttons too. So, how can I [**implement those 3 dots**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJ5wL.jpg) to be responsible with my screens???

Comment: thats not splash screen.....

Comment: possible duplicate.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380207/how-to-implement-gallery-swiping-with-dots-under

Comment: you can use ViewPager http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316931/android-view-pager-with-page-indicator

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You probably want to use ViewPager. Check out this tutorial https://medium.com/android-news/creating-an-intro-screen-for-your-app-using-viewpager-pagetransformer-9950517ea04f#.wt85fxrf5 or this sample https://github.com/lalongooo/viewpager-sample

Comment: good example, but I was using something [similar](http://www.androidsources.com/index.php/2015/08/06/android-splash-screen-and-welcome-screen-tutorial-using-android-studio/) - simplified a bit

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibilities. If you don't want to use ViewPager, you can use LinearLayout with 3 ImageView. You can create two oval shapes using drawable resources and replace them according to displayed screen. Those "dots" can have listeners used to navigation.

Answer (score 0):

1.you need to use ViewPageIndicator Library [click](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator/archive/master.zip) here to download the library.

2.Then Go to Android Studio File>New>New Module - to import the Library into your project.

3.Then add dependency in gradle `compile project(path:':viewpagelibrary')`

4.set Adapter

```
public CirclePageIndicator mCirclePageIndicator;
public ViewPager mViewPager;
void initiateViewPager(){
           mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
           mCirclePageIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
           mViewPager.setAdapter(mViewPageAdapter);
           mCirclePageIndicator.setViewPager(mViewPager);
}
```

thats all
hope it helps someone